# What is the resistance or usability considerations for new or interactive inline text behaviours?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, inline-edit

I cam across one of Bret Victor's interesting musing about [inline spellchecker behaviour](http://worrydream.com/#!/InlineSpellcheck) where he proposed a couple of alternatives to the popup box for spellcheck suggestions. I thought that the concept of inline and interlinear interactions could work for things such as tooltips or info or definitions but have not seen it used commonly in modern web applications. Is there any particular reason why it is not a more common design pattern from a design or usability point of view?

Comment: It appears quite impractical as it requires either extreme double spacing of text or a lot of text-reflow as you go. It also means that--at least on desktop--people now have to deal with two separate menus (one for spellcheck, one for contextual options)

Answer (score 1):

I see a number of potential issues with that spell checker/corrector UI.

One issue is that it clutters up your text, your (possible) errors are much more front and center than the traditional underline that indicates a possible spelling error. With the correction suggestions inline it interrupts the flow of the text. With the corrections interline it presents a different kind of clutter.

In a case in which you're often using a word that the spell checker thinks is erroneous, all that clutter could be disturbing (of course a solution for this is to be able to configure or train the spell checker, but that presents another *thing*, another complication).

I think a high percentage of my spelling errors are typos, so the underline appears immediately and I almost instinctively backspace and correct it - I don't need nor want suggestions most of the time, they would only slow me down. (I don't know if my preference here is the more common one, maybe a more precise typist would make more spelling errors than typing errors.)

I can't tell how this (Victor's spell checker UI) behaves as I type. It's possible it could be quite speedy and convenient to make corrections without grabbing the mouse, but my guess it would take some amount of practice to learn this keyboard action.

The problems Victor identifies are 1) hiding information (by the popup menu, presumably) and 2) one extra mouse click (to pop up the menu). All in all, my guess is that it's too heavy a solution to those minor problems, at least in the context of general text editing.

Comment: the proposal is not for real time typing as far as I understand - only when you explicitly use the *Spell Check...* feature that originally opens a modal window

Answer (score 1):

**Inline** interactions are disruptive to say the least. When reading, each word in a sentence is interpreted by the brain through the context of the surrounding words. By inlining spellcheck suggestions that context is essentially lost and what is spellchecking but finding the right word for the given context?

**Interlinear** interactions solve that problem but introduces many others. What if two words next to each other are wrongly spelled? There wouldn't be enough space to show both lists of words. What if the last word on a line has a long list of spelling alternatives? There is no room left to show it.

The proposal is interesting but isn't robust enough to make it work for anything but a toy example like in Victor's article.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite common on mobile keyboards now. Sort of. The line of suggestions is positioned horizontally over the keyboard not in the text.

However, Victor's very efficient solution makes one assumption the everyday user does not agree with: that users want to type first and spell check later while editing. We aren't that concerned about craft, on the whole. Most users want to fix the errors as they arise (hopefully, automatically) and the drop down format works well for that.

Another reminder that users don't always want a "better" solution.

( I hope the computer is editing this for me — I don't have time for that )

Comment: Depends very much on who exactly is the user.  Personally, I find real-time spell check (and autocomplete, etc) vastly annoying.  If I can't turn it off in an application, I won't use it if there's any practical alternative.  (Though I admit that I may not be an "everyday user", since I actually do know how to spell.)

Comment: Note that I said *every day user*. When you're talking about changing a pattern that has this kind of scale, you aren't dealing with micro preferences. For the record, I have mine turned off too. I hate inline spell checkers for the very reason Victor was trying to solve.